# How can I preform a GET request when user input equals current time?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular.js for my GET request.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ArduinoCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.response = {};
    $scope.progress = false;
    $scope.setServo = function (setting) {
        $scope.progress = true;
        var url = "http://192.168.2.4/arduino/" + setting
        $http.get(url).then(sucess, error).then(function () {
            $scope.progress = false;
        });

    }


});
```

I would like to call the setServo(setting) GET request when a time (two ints), in hours and minutes that is set by the user, matches the current time. The user inputted time is set with two range input types.

HTML code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Enter the time for daily dispense</h2>
            <input type="number" min="1" max="3" id="num"/>
            <div>
                <p>Hour: </p>
                <input type="range" min="1" max="24" name="hour" id="hour" onchange="updatedHourInput(this.value)" />

            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Minutes: </p>
                <input type="range" min="00" max="55" step="5" name="minute" id="minute" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value)" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Entered Time=  </span><span id="textHour"></span><span>:</span><span id="textMinute"></span>
                <br />
                <span>Current Time= </span><span id="time"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My JavaScript code, this is called onload in the .

```
 function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var userHour = parseInt(document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML);
    var userMinute = parseInt(document.getElementById('minute').innerHTML);
    var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value);
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
    if ((h == userHour) && (m = userMinute)) {
        setServo(num);


    }
}
```

Comment: Says my innerHTML's are NaN and "" if I take away the parseInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I can't understand why you're not binding inputs using regular `ng-model` approach:

```
<!-- Example: -->
<input type="text" ng-model="hour" />
```

Once you've bound an input to some scope's property using `ng-model`, the so-called input and property will react to changes of both (this is *two-way binding*).

In the other hand, you'll implement a `hour` and `minute` properties in your controller's `$scope`, and you won't access the DOM to get inputs' values, since Angular data-binding will set input values into these properties and viceversa when you set the properties.

If you go this way, you can `$watch` property changes and once hours and minutes are current time, you can trigger a function:

```
module.controller("X", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.hours = 0;
    $scope.minutes = 0;

    var onTimeChange = function() {
        // Eval $scope.hours and $scope.minutes
        // and trigger whatever function you want!
    }; 

    $scope.$watch("hours", onTimeChange);
    $scope.$watch("minutes", onTimeChange);
});
```

Let me give you an advise: AngularJS is about data-binding, separation of concerns and controllers, models or services shouldn't access the DOM directly - this is why data-binding exists -. Directives are the entity whithin Angular world that may access or modify the DOM using regular DOM or jQuery (or any other DOM manipulation library).

Comment: My main goal is to pass the num value into the setServo function.

Comment: @GlobalJim And what's the problem with using AngularJS approach? I don't understand what has to do Angular if you don't use data-binding to solve your issue...